# PyGObject Progress Bar in Notify.Notification

Tags: python, python-3.x, notifications, gtk3, pygobject

I am using PyGObject with Python 3 and I want to display a notification using a `Notify.Notification` which has a progress bar in it. The progress bar doesn't need to update on its own/asynchronously or anything - it can (and should) be static, updating only when I manually set a new value then tell the notification to show. I'm after something like a volume notification showing the new volume as you change it.

I have been unable to find any way to do this searching documentation such as [this](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Notify-0.7/classes/Notification.html), is this possible using PyGObject? Alternatively is there another Python 3 library which would allow this behaviour?

I'm currently showing notifications with text-based progress similar to this:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
from gi.repository import Notify

def __init___(self):
    ...
    Notify.init("Progress")
    self.notification = Notify.Notification(summary='Progress', body='0%')
    self.notification.set_image_from_pixbuf(notification_image)
    ...

def on_progress_update(self, progress):
    ...
    self.notification.update('Progress', str(progress) + '%', None)
    self.notification.show()
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after much more searching I found [this](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=9943) thread on the xfce forums discussing the use of send-notify to get xfce4-notifyd "gauges", and was able to figure out how to use `Notify.Notification.set_hint()`. So, if you want your notification to show a progress bar/status bar/gauge, you can use the following:

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
from gi.repository import GLib, Notify

Notify.init("Name")
notification = Notify.Notification()
notification.set_hint('value', GLib.Variant.new_int32(volume))
```

Points of note:

- Setting a summary and body, as seen in the original question, seems to be pointless if using this method since neither are shown, only the progress bar. An icon/image can still be shown along side the progress bar, e.g. with `notification.set_image_from_pixbuf()`
- The GLib.Variant type can be `int32`, `int64`, `double`, and possibly others of numeric type larger than `int32`, but NOT `byte` or `int16`, any `uint` type such as `uint32`, or (I would assume) any non-numeric type. Just use `int32` as fas I can tell.
- While I was using generic names like `Name` for other steps, the value for `set_hint` MUST be `'value'` with a lower case v.

Also worth noting I'm not sure if this is a unniversal method or if it only works for xfce4-notifyd, I only use xfce4-notifyd so for now I'm not concerned, but if I look into this I will try to remember to update my answer. Alternatively if anyone else knows the answer to this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[The solution by Tomha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41890837/4417769) works, just wanted to point out a general way to replicate any notification.

By running `dbus-monitor` and changing the volume, something like this should be printed somewhere along the lines, because all notifications are created via the dbus:

```
method call time=1598625454.708735 sender=:1.75 -> destination=:1.81 serial=23739 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "Xfce volume control"
   uint32 0
   string "audio-volume-medium-symbolic"
   string "Volume 46%"
   string ""
   array [
   ]
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "transient"
         variant             boolean true
      )
      dict entry(
         string "x-canonical-private-synchronous"
         variant             string ""
      )
      dict entry(
         string "value"
         variant             int32 46
      )
   ]
   int32 2000
```

Here is the hint name and value that generates the progressbar:

```
dict entry(
   string "value"
   variant             int32 46
)
```